# loop class in divs with different time javascript

Tags: javascript, class, loops, setinterval, timing

i need to change class of current element, in loop but with different timing.

in this case it happen just once :/

any suggestions thx ??

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--0 current" data-time="2500">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--1" data-time="5000">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--0" data-time="7000">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--0" data-time="9000">
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>


function myFunction() {
    var current = $('.wrapper').children(".current") 
    var timeOfVisible = $('.wrapper').children(".current").data("time");
    setInterval(function() {
        current.removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
        if ((current.next()) > $('.wrapper').children().length) {
            alert(current)
        }
    }, timeOfVisible);
}
myFunction()
```

Comment: so you want the setInterval to work on diff. data-time per div

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Is your problem that you want to chain this function?

Comment: i prepare fiddle for it  https://jsfiddle.net/xd9kw3qm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will need setTimeout instead of Interval, because you will run one delay per element. Second - you need to call your function recursively for this to repeat in a loop.
Here is working js for you:

```
function changeClass() {
  var current = $('.wrapper .wrapper-item.current');
  if(current.length > 0) {
     var timeOfVisible = current.data("time");
     setTimeout(function(){
    current.removeClass('current');
    if (current.next().length > 0)
        current.next().addClass('current');
    else
      $('.wrapper .wrapper-item').first().addClass('current');
      changeClass();
  }, timeOfVisible); 
  }
};

changeClass();
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dZOVjZ?editors=1111).

Also, if you don't want infinite loop, use this instead:

```
function changeClass() {
  var current = $('.wrapper .wrapper-item.current');
  if(current.length > 0) {
     var timeOfVisible = current.data("time");
     setTimeout(function(){
    current.removeClass('current');
    if (current.next().length > 0) {
      current.next().addClass('current');
      changeClass(); 
    }
  }, timeOfVisible); 
  }
};

changeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain the function then you need to add the main function loop to the callback of the setInterval.

simply done this is:

```
function myFunction() {
    var current = $('.wrapper').children(".current") 
    var timeOfVisible = $('.wrapper').children(".current").data("time");
    setInterval(function() {
        current.removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
        if ((current.next()) > $('.wrapper').children().length) {
            alert(current)
        }
        myFunction();
    }, timeOfVisible);
}
```

All I have done is moved the function call `myFunction()` to inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by calling the function **TWO** times insted of just one.. & call it recursively i.e. within itself

You can check the console....

here is a working snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 function myFunction() {
   
    var current = $('.wrapper').children(".current"); 
    var timeOfVisible = $('.wrapper').children(".current").data("time");
  
    setInterval(function() {
        current.removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
  console.log($(current))
        if ((current.next()) > $('.wrapper').children().length) {
            alert(current)
        }
  myFunction()
    }, timeOfVisible);
}
myFunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--0 current" data-time="2500">
        <div class="item">0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--1" data-time="5000">
        <div class="item">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--0" data-time="7000">
        <div class="item">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-item wrapper-item--0" data-time="9000">
        <div class="item">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```